# Is it possible to make a javascript/html mutiplayer game?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a **javascript/html** mutiplayer game (if I have a server, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

[Rawkets - MMO using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript WebSockets](http://rawkets.com/)

You can look at its source code: https://github.com/robhawkes/rawkets

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. However such an environment has lots of limitations and is not the very best choice in many situations. Actually, everything depends on type of the game. Chess or some card game? Sure! But real-time FPS? Maybe some day...